# How to continue to another activity in android studio after login to google and facebook account

Tags: android, facebook

I need help here, I just finish to create a login to google and facebook account using firebase.
But I don't know how to continue to another activity as when I finish to Login I only see the Logout button and the app crashed

here is the code on the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
  private static final int RC_SIGHN_IN = 0;
  private FirebaseAuth auth;



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      if(auth.getCurrentUser()!= null)
      {
         //user already signed in
          Log.d("AUTH", auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

      }
      else
      {
          startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                  .createSignInIntentBuilder().setProviders(
                          AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER,
                          AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                          AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                  .build(),RC_SIGHN_IN);

      }
      findViewById(R.id.log_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);


  }
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if(requestCode==RC_SIGHN_IN)
      {
          if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
          {
              //User logged in
              Log.d("AUTH", auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

          }
          else
          {
              //User not AUTHENTICATED
              Log.d("AUTH","NOT AUTHENTICATED");
          }
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
      if(view.getId()==R.id.log_out_button)
      {
          AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
                  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                          Log.d("AUTH","User Logged Out");

                          finish();

                      }
                  });
      }
  }
}
```

Crash details

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.matan.gesta_app, PID: 3361
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {  }} to activity {com.example.matan.gesta_app/com.example.matan.gesta_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4053)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.matan.gesta_app.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:54)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6915)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: `app crashed` use logcat to see and post the error details

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I added the error from the logcat, thank for your response

Comment: `auth` is not initialized

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh   so what do i need to do?

Comment: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011496/4936904)

Comment: Sorry but this is not helpful as I write the code above according to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Why did your app crash? Can you post the log?

After the user has logged in successfully, you should get a callback in the onActivityResult()

If the user has logged in, start your new Activity inside the Result_OK block

```
 if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        //User logged in
        Log.d("AUTH", auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
      // Start your activity here

    }
```