# Null value in FirebaseUser getEmail()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Uh, sorry here cause I need a little help. I checked the web but doesn't seem to find a solution yet.

I got an error here:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference
>           at com.flipflop.flipflop_gmap.Utility.FirebaseMethods$1.onComplete(FirebaseMethods.java:63)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

Here's my code:

```
public void registerNewEmail(final String email, String password, final String username){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Timber.tag(TAG).d("createUserWithEmail:onComplete:%s", task.isSuccessful());
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Authentication Failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    else if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                        if (user.getEmail() != null) ***ERROR HERE***
                            sendVerificationEmail();

                        try {
                            userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Timber.tag(TAG).e(e, "onComplete: get userID failed: %s", userID);
                        }

                        Timber.tag(TAG).d("onComplete: Authstate changed: %s", userID);
                    }

                }
            });
}

public void sendVerificationEmail(){
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    if(user != null){
        user.sendEmailVerification()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Timber.tag(TAG).d("onComplete: Email sent");
                        }else{
                            Timber.tag(TAG).d("onComplete: Email failed");
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Couldn't send verification email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

This is how I called the method:

```
email = mEmail.getText().toString();
username = mUsername.getText().toString();
password = mPassword.getText().toString();
firebaseMethods.registerNewEmail(email, password, username);
```

Those fields are all filled, but I just can't see why getEmail() is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010081/why-firebaseauth-getinstance-getcurrentuser-is-returning-null-value-in-andro

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen how do you guys managed to find these duplicate post so fast, I google for like an hour...lemme see the thread thx

Comment: Uh, I think mine is different from that.

Comment: Well, `user` is clearly `null` here since `user.getEmail()` throws an exception. The link I provided has the same issue, however your code might differ from the other one of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take a look at the Firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser(), we can see the following:

> Returns the currently signed-in FirebaseUser or null if there is none.
>
> Use getCurrentUser() != null to check if a user is signed in.

So, we can say that in your code the user does not exist or is not signed in (yet). So, make sure that your user is actually logged in.

Comment: Oh, lemme try fix it and see. Thanks for the help, have a nice day.